# Array command in Latex

Tags: math-mode, errors, r, markdown

I wonder may I ask about why I received the error note from R-Markdown that

### ! LaTeX Error: \begin{array} on input line 569 ended by \end{equation*}.

```
    #1,

Let X =
\[ 
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
1 & X1\\
\dots & \dots\\
1 & X_n 
\end{array}\right)
%\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
10 & 0\\ 
0 & 5
\end{array}\right)
\]

Then, \[X^T\] =
\[
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & \dots & 1\\
X_1 & \dots & X_N
\end{array}\right)
\]

\[
X \times X^T =
\]

\[\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
1 & X1\\
\dots & \dots\\
1 & X_n
\end{array}\right)\]
\[\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
1 & \dots & 1\\ 
X_1 & \dots & X_N
\end{array}\right) 
\]

=

\[
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
n & \sum_{i}^n X_i\\
\sum_{i}^n X_i & \sum_{i}^n X_i^2
\end{array}\right)
\]

#2,

\[(X^TX)^{-1}\]=

\[1/[n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - (\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)^2] 
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 & -\sum_{i=1}^n Xi\\
- \sum _{i=1}^n X_i & n
\end{array}\right) \]
=\[1/[n \sum _{i=1}^n X_i^2 - ( \sum X_i)^2] [n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - ( \sum _{i=1} ^n X_i)^2]\]
=1
```

The above are the code I only had about the command{array}, I am sorry I am new to R-Markdown and I cannot find the line 569 since my last line is line 373. Thank you very much for any suggestions!
Appreciated!

Comment: Incidentally, you should really check your math. I believe there are two particularly troublesome issues. First, if `X` is an `nx2` matrix, the dimension of `XX^T` must be `nxn`, not `2x2`. Second, if `n>1`, the matrix `XX^T` is not of full rank and its inverse does not exist -- let alone be equal to scalar `1`. Are you maybe referring to `X^T X` and its inverse? By the way, the inverse of `X^T X` should be a `2x2` matrix, *not* the number `1`. If the math isn't correct, it's not all that productive to try to fix up the LaTeX code, is it?

Answer (score 2):

I made your code compile and also replaced the arrays by matrices where I thought this would be appropriate. Notice also that there are environments like `align` that allow you to write aligned multiline equations. So here is some modification of your code that can be compiled and has some minor corrections.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Let 
\[ 
X =\begin{pmatrix}
1 & X_1\\
\dots & \dots\\
1 & X_n 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
10 & 0\\ 
0 & 5
\end{pmatrix}
\]
Then, 
\[
X^T =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \dots & 1\\
X_1 & \dots & X_N
\end{pmatrix}
\]
and
\begin{align*}
X \times X^T &=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & X1\\
\dots & \dots\\
1 & X_n
\end{pmatrix}\,
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \dots & 1\\ 
X_1 & \dots & X_N
\end{pmatrix} \\
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
n & \sum_{i}^n X_i\\
\sum_{i}^n X_i & \sum_{i}^n X_i^2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
as well as
\begin{align*}
(X^TX)^{-1}&=
\frac{1}{n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - \left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)^2}
\begin{pmatrix}
\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 & -\sum_{i=1}^n Xi\\
- \sum _{i=1}^n X_i & n
\end{pmatrix} \\
&=\frac{1}{n \sum _{i=1}^n X_i^2 - ( \sum X_i)^2} 
\left[n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - \left( \sum _{i=1} ^n X_i\right)^2\right]
\\
 &=1
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is not hard to see, though, that the first equation does not make too much sense in view of the equations below it. On the other hand, I did not just dare to remove the right-most matrix, but I am sure you will know what to do with it.

Comment: A heroic try! :-) See the comment I just left under the initial posting...

Comment: @Mico Thanks! I agree with you except that I think one may partly save this by arguing that the notation indicates a [dyadic product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics) and `X^T` is a column and `X` a row vector. But yes, the notation is very unclear.

Comment: My guess is that `X` represents the regressors from a bivariate regression: a constant term (`1`) and the "independent variable" `x`. We may never know for sure...

Comment: @Mico Could very well be. No idea. My only intention here was to provide something that runs through and to inform the OP that `array` may not be the way to go.